# AS3, error 1180 call to a possibly undefined method Nivel1, Adobe animate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, undefined

thank you tatactic for answer, i already fixed that problem but i have this, here are all the classes for the game i like to make but the player is no moving, you can help me here, that is the problem. thnks

Nivel1 Class :

```
package Codigos.Niveles {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import Codigos.Jugador;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import Codigos.CamaraVirtual;

    public class Nivel1 extends MovieClip {

       public function Nivel1() {
          main.nuevoJugador = new Jugador();
          addChild(main.nuevoJugador);
          main.nuevoJugador.x = 34;
          main.nuevoJugador.y = 334;
          main.nuevaCamara = new CamaraVirtual();
          addChild(main.nuevaCamara);
          main.nuevaCamara.x = 400;
          main.nuevaCamara.y = 240;
          addEventListener("EnterFrame",nivel1Eventos);
       }
       private function nivel1Eventos(e:Event){
           if(main.nuevoJugador.x<=150){
               MovieClip(root).Nivel.x+=5;
               MovieClip(root).escenario.x+=5;
               main.nuevoJugador.x+=5;
           }
           else if(main.nuevoJugador.x>=650){
               MovieClip(root).Nivel.x-=5;
               MovieClip(root).escenario.x-=5;
               main.nuevoJugador.x-=5;
           }
        }  

     }

}
```

Main class:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import Codigos.Jugador;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import Codigos.CamaraVirtual;

    public class main extends MovieClip {

        public static var nuevoJugador:Jugador;
        public static var nuevaCamara:CamaraVirtual;
        public static var TemporalPuntos:int = 0;
        public static var DerechaVar:Boolean = false;
        public static var IzquierdaVar:Boolean = false;
        public static var SaltoVar:Boolean = false;

        public function main() {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
        }
    }

}
```

Jugador class (player):

```
package Codigos {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class Jugador extends MovieClip {

        public var VelocidadX:int = 5;
        public var VelocidadY:int = 1;
        public var Limite:int = 10;
        public var Salto:int = -12;
        public function Jugador() {
            addEventListener("EnterFrame",Moverme);
        }
        private function Moverme(e:Event){
            var NivelaTocar = MovieClip(root).Nivel;
            if(NivelaTocar.hitTestPoint(x,y + height/2,true)){
                while(NivelaTocar.hitTestPoint(x,-1 + y +height/2,true)){
                    y--;
                }
                VelocidadY=0;
                if(main.SaltoVar){
                    VelocidadY=Salto;
                    y+=VelocidadY;
                }
            }
            else if(NivelaTocar.hitTestPoint(x,y-height/2,true)){
                VelocidadY = VelocidadY * -0.5;
                y += VelocidadY;
                while(NivelaTocar.hitTestPoint(x, y - height / 2,true)){
                    y++;
                    main.SaltoVar = false;
                }
            }

            else {
                y+=VelocidadY * 1.5;
                main.SaltoVar = false;
                if(VelocidadY <= Limite){
                    VelocidadY++;
                }
            }

            while(NivelaTocar.hitTestPoint(x + width / 2, y , true)){
                x--;
            }
            while(NivelaTocar.hitTestPoint(x - width / 2, y , true)){
                x++;
            }
            movimientosReales();
        }
        private function movimientosReales(){
            if(main.DerechaVar){
                x+=VelocidadX;
                scaleX = 1;
            }
            else if(main.IzquierdaVar){
                x-=VelocidadX;
                scaleX = -1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

CamaraVirtual class (virtual camera):

```
package Codigos {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class CamaraVirtual extends MovieClip {


        public function CamaraVirtual() {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Botones);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Soltar);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, TodaCam);
            Puntos.text = String(int(0));
        }
        private function Botones(e:MouseEvent){
            if(e.target == Derecha){
                main.DerechaVar = true;
            }
            else if(e.target == Izquierda){
                main.IzquierdaVar = true;
            }
            else if(e.target == Salto){
                main.SaltoVar = true;
            }
        }
        private function Soltar(e:MouseEvent){
            main.DerechaVar = false;
            main.IzquierdaVar = false;
            main.SaltoVar = false;
        }
        private function TodaCam(e:Event){
            Puntos.text = String(int(main.TemporalPuntos));
        }
    }

}
```

Moneda Class (coin):

```
package Codigos {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class Moneda extends MovieClip {


        public function Moneda() {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tocar);
        }
        private function tocar(e:Event){
            if(hitTestObject(main.nuevoJugador)){
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, tocar);
                main.TemporalPuntos++;
                parent.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `var nuevoNivel1 : Nivel1 = new Nivel1();`. Next time post **actual code** text, not pictures of code. Explain what your error **actually** says.

Comment: Please use English names for your variables and methods!

Comment: Packages names should start with lowercase "codigos.niveles", variables names should too.
Classes Should always start with uppercase as you did : "Nivel1".
Methods should always start with lowercase.
You should consider this before to post a question.

Comment: This is difficult for anybody to answer to your question if this question is unclear or not well formated. @Brandon

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor method **Nivel1()** *comment all the code and just try this*:

```
public function Nivel1(){
        trace(main.nuevoJugador);
        /*
        main.nuevoJugador = new Jugador();
        addChild(main.nuevoJugador);
        main.nuevoJugador.x = 25;
        main.nuevoJugador.y = 344;
        */
}
```

What is the output?
I suppose that

```
trace(main.nuevoJugador);
```

or just:

```
trace(main);
```

> will output undefined / null / or will throw an Error? Is that right?

because "main" is not defined in the "Nivel1" Class...
Am I wrong?

And please, could you post the **"Jugador" Class** too.

> Not an image, but the code!!!

Just copy and paste the code, then select the code you added, then click on **"code sample <pre><code> Ctrl+K"** like in the image below:

[image]

**So, users may edit / change your code in another answer without spending time to rewrite all the code provided by a prinstscreen (This is a huge waste of time for the community here on stackoverflow)!**

Comment: @Brandon feedback?

Comment: sorry for not responding've had problems with my pc. I've fixed that problem, but if you can help me with something else.

I have done the codes to appears  and move the player in the level, but does not move.

Comment: sorry im new in this, i edit and put all the classes, i dont know why the player is no moving  . @tatactic

Comment: Did you try to trace "main"? : trace(main); I don't seen any reference to main in your classes.@Brandon..